# Missing output on register file simulation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, cpu-registers, xilinx

I'm trying to simulate a register file. My issues is that I am not getting an output for `aData` or `bData`. I suspect I have an issue with my assignments, but I'm not sure.

My code for the module:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module registerfile(
input  [4:0]    aAddress,
input  [4:0]    bAddress,
input  [4:0]    dAddress,
input [31:0]       dData,
input              write,
input       [3:0] status,
input              clock,
input              reset,
output reg [31:0]  aData,
output reg [31:0]  bData
);
 
reg [31:0] registerfile [0:31];
integer i;

initial begin
for (i = 0; i <32; i = i +1 )
    begin
    registerfile[i] = 0;
    end
end

always @ (*)
begin
    if (aAddress == 5'b00000)
        begin
        aData = 32'h0000_0000; //reg[0] already holds 0
        end
    else
        begin
        aData = registerfile[aAddress]; //contents of register file at aAddress sent out to aData
        end

end

always @ (*)
begin
    if (bAddress == 5'b00000)
        begin
        bData = 32'h0000_0000; //reg[0] already holds 0
        end
    else
        begin
        bData = registerfile[bAddress]; //contents of register file at bAddress sent out to bData
        end
end

always @ (posedge clock)
begin
    if (reset == 1)
        begin
            for (i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1)
                begin
                registerfile[i] <= 0;
                aData = 0;
                bData = 0;
                end
        end
    else if ((write == 1) && (dAddress != 0) && (dAddress != 31)) //reserve reg 0 for 0 constant and 31 for status register
        begin
            registerfile[dAddress] <= dData; //store dData
            if (aAddress == dAddress) //handles special case
                aData <= dData;
            if (bAddress == dAddress) //handles special case
                bData <= dData;
        end
        
    registerfile[31] <= {28'd0, status}; //status flags
end

endmodule
```

My code for the simulation:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module registerfile_test;

// Inputs
reg [4:0] aAddress;
reg [4:0] bAddress;
reg [4:0] dAddress;
reg [31:0] dData;
reg write;
reg [3:0] status;
reg clock;
reg reset;

// Outputs
wire [31:0] aData;
wire [31:0] bData;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
registerfile uut (
    .aAddress(aAddress), 
    .bAddress(bAddress), 
    .dAddress(dAddress), 
    .dData(dData), 
    .write(write), 
    .status(status), 
    .clock(clock), 
    .reset(reset), 
    .aData(aData), 
    .bData(bData)
);

reg [31:0] registerfile [0:31];
reg [31:0] testData1, testData2;

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    aAddress = 0;
    bAddress = 0;
    dAddress = 0;
    dData = 0;
    write = 0;
    clock = 0;
    reset = 0;

    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100;
    testData1 = 32'hFF0F_00FF;
    testData2 = 32'h00F0_FF00;
    aAddress  =      5'b00101;
    bAddress  =      5'b00010;
    dAddress  =      5'b00110;
    dData     = 32'hFFFF_FFF0; //used to test
    write     =             1;
    status    =       4'b0000;
    //write     =             0;
    
    registerfile[aAddress] = testData1;
    registerfile[bAddress] = testData2;
    end
           
    // Add stimulus here    
    always begin
    #10 clock = ~clock;
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning to `aData` in two separate `always` blocks.  You shouldn't do that.  Likewise for `bData`.

Also, `reset` is always 0 in your testbench.